# Math.random into an array and then printing array into 10 lines of 10

Tags: java, arrays, random, generated

So I am just trying to figure out a way of putting randomly generated numbers into an array list. I am also trying to just put 10 numbers on a line for 10 lines for a total of 100 numbers printed out.

This is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Part1 {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int[] list = new int[100];

            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
               System.out.println("");
               for(int g=0; g<9; g++){

                   for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

                       int rand = (int )(Math.random() * 500 + 1);

                       System.out.print(rand + " ");
                   }               
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

This is the closest I think I have come to getting it some what right
but here is another one I had tried:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Part1 {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int[] list = new int[100];

        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

            int rand = (int )(Math.random() * 500 + 1);


            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
               System.out.println(rand + " ");
               for(int g=0; g<9; g++){
                  System.out.print("");
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just trying to understand how to put these random numbers into an array and then being able to print the numbers out into lines of 10. Thanks for hint and/or help in advanced.

Comment: In what way are your results unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a one-dimensional array:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] list = new int[100];
int count = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    list[i] =  rand.nextInt(500) + 1; 

    // check if you're at the 10th number in the line
    if (count % 10 > 0) System.out.print(list[i] + " "); // print on this line
    else System.out.println(list[i] + " "); // print on a new line
    count++;
}
```

---

Using a two-dimesional array (recommended):

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] list = new int[10][10];

    for (int r = 0; r < list.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < list[r].length; c++)
        {
            list[r][c] =  rand.nextInt(500) + 1;
            System.out.print(list[r][c] + " "); // print on this line
        }
        // this occurs when you're done displaying each row, so skip a line.
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

Using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int count = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list.add(rand.nextInt(500) + 1); 

    // check if you're at the 10th number in the line
    if (count % 10 > 0) System.out.print(list.get(i) + " "); // print on this line
    else System.out.println(list.get(i) + " "); // print on a new line
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the one dimensional array not the arraylist THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy :)

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Uno {

    public static void main(String ... args){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] a = new int[100];
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            a[i] = rand.nextInt();
            System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
            // perform modulo division by 10 to check if 10 results have been printed and add a new line
            if( (i+1)%10==0 ) { System.out.println(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And here I was trying to pedagogically ask leading questions :P

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[]args){

        int[] list = new int[100];

        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

            int rand = (int )(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
            list[i] = rand;
        }

        int lineNumberCounter = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){


            if(lineNumberCounter == 10){
                System.out.println();
                lineNumberCounter=0;
            }

            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
            lineNumberCounter++;

        }
 }
```

You can set and print in the same for loop by modifying the above to:

```
   public static void main(String[]args){

        int[] list = new int[100];
        int lineNumberCounter = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

            int rand = (int )(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
            list[i] = rand;

            if(lineNumberCounter == 10){
                System.out.println();
                lineNumberCounter=0;
            }

            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
            lineNumberCounter++;



        }




 }
```